# ISTIO: telemetry traffic not showing correctly in grafana & kiali

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, istio, telemetry

I am new to kubernetes & istio,
trying to apply the bookinfo tutorial to my personal project, i don't get the same results when monitoring traffic through kiali ui or grafana ui.

i believe i didn't change much from the bookinfo project, here is the config i used (using helm)

```
##################################################################################################
# Webapp services
##################################################################################################
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Values.service.name }}-svc"
  namespace: "{{ .Values.service.namespace }}"
  labels:
    app: "{{ .Values.service.name }}"
    service: "{{ .Values.service.name }}-svc"
spec:
  ports:
  - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
    name: "{{ .Values.service.name }}-http"
  selector:
    app: "{{ .Values.service.name }}"
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Values.service.name }}-{{ .Values.service.version }}"
  namespace: "{{ .Values.service.namespace }}"
  labels:
    app: "{{ .Values.service.name }}"
    version: "{{ .Values.service.version }}"
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.productionDeployment.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "{{ .Values.service.name }}"
      version: "{{ .Values.service.version }}"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "{{ .Values.service.name }}"
        version: "{{ .Values.service.version }}"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: "{{ .Values.service.name }}"
        image: "{{ .Values.productionDeployment.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.productionDeployment.image.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.productionDeployment.image.pullPolicy }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.service.port }}
---
```

and here's the istio config i used:

```
##################################################################################################
# Webapp gateway & virtual service
##################################################################################################
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Values.service.name }}-gateway"
  namespace: "{{ .Values.service.namespace }}"
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Values.service.name }}"
  namespace: "{{ .Values.service.namespace }}"
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - "{{ .Values.service.name }}-gateway"
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: "{{ .Values.service.name }}-svc"
        port:
          number: {{ .Values.service.port }}
---
```

this is what i see in kiali:
[image]

and in grafana: (notice there is no service Request volume)
[image]

however in prometheus i see traces:
[image]

Comment: on kiali screentshot it says `not enough traffic to generate chart` Did you perform any workload on your service?

Comment: @A_Suh yess i did, the same traffic i performed on the bookinfo app i did on my app